# expected value of an exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

I've been stuck at this problem for hours now. So first I know that the expected value of $X\sim\operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$ is $1/\lambda.$ But I can't figure out what the expected value is given this information:

$X\sim\operatorname{Exponential}(3)$ and $Y=\exp(2x)$

So, how do I calculate the $\operatorname E[Y]$? A step by step would be helpful, I've been stuck for hours.

Answer (score 2):

First, if $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$, then it has a p.d.f. given by $f_\lambda(x) = \lambda \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda x}$. By the definition of expectation:

$$ \mathrm{E}[Y] = \mathrm{E}[\mathrm{e}^{2X}] = \int_0^\infty \mathrm e^{2x} f_3(x) \mathrm{d} x = 3 \int_0 ^\infty \mathrm{e}^{2x}\mathrm{e}^{ - 3 x}\mathrm d x = 3 \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x}\mathrm{d}x = 3.$$

Comment: Quick reality check in R: `x = rexp(10^7, 3); y = exp(2*x); mean(y)` returns 2.987912, and
`2*sd(y)/sqrt(10^7)` returns 0.01555788, indicating that the answ is within $2.99\pm 0.0156.$ (+1)  // Random variable $Y$ is extremely right-skewed; exponential RV $X$ is already right skewed, so $Y$ even more so.

Comment: While reality checks with programs are important for comprehension, they do not replace good old math :) Always remember that pseudorandom generators are only approximations of random numbers!

Comment: Agreed. My reason for doing 'reality checks' is that there are many wrong answers on the site and rough simulations are often good enough to identify mistakes. I don't usually upvote without verifying answ somehow--check math, alt method, or sim.// Expts have shown that pseudo RNG in R is more accurate than physical manipulation, such as tossing coins or dice, perhaps better than 'shot noise' in circuits. But there is always random simulation error. (And sometimes, of course, programming errors.)

Comment: Yes, on that we agree! There is nothing better than checking gut feelings in simulation before doing a lot of math :) We could also agree that errors due to RNGs are way more unlikely than errors in the math :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X\sim\mathsf{Expo}(\lambda)$ and $Y=e^{aX}$ with $\lambda>a>0$. Then for $y>1$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y) &= \mathbb P\left(e^{aX}\leqslant y\right)\\
&= \mathbb P\left(X\leqslant \frac{\log y}a\right)\\
&= 1 - e^{-\frac{\lambda}a\log y}\\
&= 1 - \left(e^{\log y}\right)^{-\frac\lambda a}\\
&= 1 - y^{-\frac\lambda a}.
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \int_1^\infty \left(1-\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y)\right)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_1^\infty y^{-\frac\lambda a}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac\lambda{\lambda-a}.
\end{align}
If $\lambda=3$ and $a=2$ then this is equal to $3$.